# Heroku DB Migration Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Getting a migration error when I try to migrate my database on Heroku. Found a solution on here offering this advice:

```
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
rake db:migrate
```

but it hasn't made a difference. The error starts like this:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "property_id" of relation "bookings" does not exist
```

I don't have a property_id column anymore as this got changed in later migrations locally.
My migrations work locally by the way so why not on Heroku?

Comment: rake db:migrate will migrate your local database. Try "heroku run rake db:migrate"  and tell us what happens please. Please check [this heroku document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake).

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your Schema so I can see if you have a column "property_id".

If you do not then you will have to add this column property_id to the bookings class.

Also try

rake db:drop
rake db:migrate

what happens?

Comment: that would be a step backwards wouldn't it? I have used heroku rake db:schema:load and this has solved the problem

Comment: I thought you said you tried this and it gave you the error. You should not have to load the schema if all of you migrations are correct. Please post your schema and current errors

Comment: Yeah it didn't work and then it did so Im totally confused! ha ha thanks for you help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate data to or from your heroku postgres database and your local one? It seems like the schema_migrations table is out of sync with reality on your heroku instance.

If you can lose all data, I would just start over. The following command will wipe your entire database, destroy all tables:

`heroku pg:reset # destructive action, careful`

After that, try `heroku run rake db:migrate` again; it should work.

If that does not work, then you'll probably have to manually inspect the schema_migrations table and make sure that the correct migrations have been applied and perhaps manually put it back in a consistent state.

This situation is quite abnormal and can only have happened by manually touching this data or schema. Because postgres supports transactional DDL, it cannot have happened via `heroku run rake db:migrate` alone, as in case of errors the whole migration rolls back and the database is left in a consistent state.